# AWS Error Parsing JSON in PayloadParserTrait on second request to Lex bot

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I've got a Lex bot which I am SMSing with.  The first SMS gets the correct reply to invoke the bot and it replies correctly, but my next SMS causes an exception: `Aws/Api/Parser/Exception/ParserException: Error parsing JSON: Syntax error in /path/to/Aws/Api/Parser/PayloadParserTrait.php`

Neither message (the first, which worked; the second which caused the exception) had any special characters in it (so no concerns about an unescaped ' or " or anything like that).

The stack trace from error message is:

```
 Aws/AwsClient->postContent( )                  .../twilio.php: 71
 Aws/AwsClient->__call( )                       .../twilio.php: 71
 Aws/AwsClient->execute( )                      .../AwsClientTrait.php: 84
 GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise->wait( )            .../AwsClientTrait.php: 63
 GuzzleHttp/Promise/RejectedPromise->wait( )    .../Promise.php: 65
```

When I tried to dive into the AWS code to trace the `postContent` call I'm not able to find where the function exists (it doesn't appear in `AwsClient.php`) so I'm not able to add better debugging statements.

**How can I go about debugging what is wrong here?**